# Appending variable in PHP causes Syntax Error

Tags: php, variables, syntax, syntax-error

What is wrong with this php code?

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from news where isActive = 1 and partnerid_fk = '$partnerid'");
$news = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    news .= "<li class='news-item'><a href='#'>" . $row['news'] . "</a></li>";
}
```

Error on the news append line:

```
Syntax error.
```

Comment: no dollar sign in variable `news` in the loop

Comment: you forgot a `$` in `news`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot your dollar sign:

```
news .=
```

should be

```
$news .=
```

Comment: I completely focused on the right part of the line :) thank you